# deleting a workflow if its run again

Tags: 2010, workflow

basically I have a workflow that runs if something has been modified or created. But if you modify it and then upload a new version replacing the old one it starts a new workflow not replacing the old one.
Is there a way of deleting the old workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove older running workflows

1. Open the context menu of the item and click on Workflows
2. On the Workflows screen older stalled workflows will be listed under "Running Workflows". Click the workflow that you want to remove.
3. You will be able to cancel the stalled workflow the next screen.

To remove older version definitions

1. Click on the workflow settings on the Library tab on the ribbon.
2. Select the appropriate item in the dorpdown named "These workflows are configured to run on items of this type".
3. Click on "Remove a workflow"
4. Select the remove radio button for the workflow that you want to remove and click OK

Regards

Comment: don't want to do this manually, when the new workflow is created I want it to delete the old workflow

Comment: I am not sure if that is possible. Maybe once you are done finalizing your workflow you can delete all the test versions all at once.

Comment: it keeps older instances around if there are items currently inflight. As those resolve, the older instances should drop off automatically